# How to set an environment variable in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

Trying to set an env var using robot script

```
${res}=  Set Environment Variable  ABCDE  12345
```

But when I check the env vars from my shell, I am not able to find it!

[image: grep-ing the env var key in shell]

Robot Logs:

[image: Robot logs]

Comment: Side note: the [Set Environment Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Set%20Environment%20Variable) keyword does not return anything. So, it is useless to store the result in a variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment variables are local to the process in which they are created. They are inherited to child processes, but not to parents. That's why you can't see them in the calling process. *ix shells have a special `export` command to export environment variables, but there is no export feature in Robot Framework. So, AFAIK this is not possible.